# Woocommerce checkout "Unexpected token" with pretty links

Tags: json, wordpress, mod-rewrite, woocommerce, caddy

I have a Wordpress e-commerce (With Woocommerce) running on my VPS (With Caddy -> NGinx)

Before i had index.php in my uri so i added in my config file theses lines to rewrite uri and be able to activate pretty links.

Perfect, it works ! Now i have www.myWebsite.com/shop/ instead of www.myWebsite.com/index.php/shop/

But, this create an error in Woocommerce cart. Indeed, i can't anymore fast-add product in my cart and checkout. I have this JSON Error :

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Of course, i search on Stack and Google, a lot of people have this issue but not for the same reason. So i try to disable mod_rewrite and.... tadaaa it's work.

So do you know how fix this issue with Woocommerce and Mod_rewrite ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem. I don't know why this rewrite work better than the old one... If someone can explain to me !

The old mod_rewrite :

```
rewrite {
  regexp .*
  ext    /
  to     /index.php?_url={uri}
}
```

The new one who fixed the issue :

```
rewrite {
    if {path} not_match ^\/wp-admin
    to {path} {path}/ /index.php?{query}
}
```

Now, i can add to cart and checkout it's work. **Prefer the second rewrite example if you have the same issue.**